# Content scrapers and Django

Tags: django, architecture

I have an application built with Django. Part of it relies on data that I aggregate from other websites. Wondering how I should approach building the scraper/aggregator.

The advantages I see of building it as a Django app is

1. the ability to use Django's models & database API
2. the ability to use Django's other methods

On the other hand I think the disadvantage would be scalability in the long run.

**Should I build the scraper/aggregator as an app in my Django project or as a separate script that runs on its own?**

Would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of your points require it to run [within Django](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/). And since it will not be dependent on the web/HTTP interface, having it be a separate module is the only option that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I just have published a Django app django-dynamic-scraper on [GitHub](https://github.com/holgerd77/django-dynamic-scraper), which is build on top of the scraping framework [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) and where you can build Scrapy scrapers in the Django admin and  use Django model classes to store your scraped data, maybe this is of some use for people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a django app, it will only run when someone loads the page. That could slow the loading.

Making another script could be a nicer idea but could produce inaccurate data.

I think it actually depends on the context.